# Determine private resolvable Bluetooth LE address

Tags: c#, uwp

I have written an application that uses the UWP classes to offer a [GATT-Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-server) (i. e. my laptop functions as a BLE peripheral).

I can successfully advertise, connect, and use it, but there's one thing I cannot figure out: how can I find out the current private resolvable address that the central is seeing?

My bluetooth adapter appears to have the internal address `9C:B6:D0:XX:YY:ZZ`. I can find and confirm that address in various ways:

- `BluetoothAdapter.GetDefaultAsync().AsTask().Result.BluetoothAddress.ToString("X12")` returns `"9CB6D0XXYYZZ"` as result in the direct window of Visual Studio.
- If I add a breakpoint in any read request handler, then `GattReadRequestedEventArgs.Session.DeviceId.Id` is `"BluetoothLE#BluetoothLE9c:b6:d0:xx:yy:zz-gg:hh:ii:jj:kk:ll"`.
- `Device Manager > Bluetooth > {Device Name} > Properties > Advanced` shows `9c:b6:d0:xx:yy:zz`.

I'm using the "nRF Connect" app for Android to connect to my artificial peripheral and operate on its BLE services and characteristics, and it works great. However, the address that nRF Connect shows is a different one, for example "5F:69:8A:DD:C9:ED". It also changes every time I restart the GATT-Server.

I suppose this is a private resolvable address, used to hide the actual adapter's address for privacy reasons. But I cannot seem to find a way to determine that address from the code in the GATT server. All I know is that it is neither the BluetoothAdapter.BluetoothAddress, nor part of the `GattReadRequestedEventArgs.Session.DeviceId.Id`, because both contain only the internal address that never changes, and the `gg:hh:ii:jj:kk:ll` part mentioned above is yet another address (but not the one nRF Connect shows).

Comment: Your address starting with `5F` is most likely a "resolvable private address" and not a static random address. Resolvable private addresses start with 4, 5, 6 or 7 and static random ones with c, d, e or f. What do you need the address for anyway? If you bond the devices then the central can use the IRK to resolve the resolvable private address to look up the bonding entry which will contain your `9c:b6...` identity address.

Comment: @Emil The program tries to emulate a device that doesn't use address mapping, and in real life the device knows its own MAC address and does things with it. It would be nice if the emulation was perfect and invisible for the central connecting to the emulator.

Comment: So, you want get bluetooth's mac address ?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I want to determine the bluetooth address that the central (in this case the smartphone) currently sees. The one that changes on every GATT Server restart, the 5F:... one, the one that's not in the device manager or `BluetoothAdapter.BluetoothAddress` or `GattReadRequestedEventArgs.Session.DeviceId.Id`.

Comment: @LWChris is there a functional reason for this information? Or do you simply want to ease debugging your application?  If it's the latter the WDK contains a tool called BTVS.exe which is a virtual sniffer, it allows you to view the HCI commands to the radio. You'll see us setting the private resolvable address.

Comment: The API returns a Static Address and the Advertisment contains the private Rotating Address. There is no way in UWP to get the **private rotating address** and this is by design.

Comment: @FrankGorgenyi My program tries to emulate a peripheral (that uses static random addresses per unit) that my company develops. A partner company is currently developing an app to operate our peripheral, implementing against my emulator. Sometimes the app will include the MAC address and the peripheral should compare it to its known address to make sure the data was actually addressed to it. But my programm cannot emulate this because the sent address (what's actually seen from the central) will differ from what the program thinks the central will see.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT You comment appears to answer my question perfectly. If you could kindly write that again as answer, then I can and will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Determine private resolvable Bluetooth LE address

For API Address and the Private Rotating Address. The API returns a Static Address and the advertisement contains the private Rotating Address.
There is no way in UWP to get the private rotating address and this is by design.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind that design? I get that you want to randomize your address to the outside world to prevent tracking, but why would you want to prevent apps on the inside to gain access to this randomized address?

Comment: Probably so that nobody builds an app that assumes a steady address when it is volatile by design?